# In group theory, what is meant by the structure of a group?

Tags: group-theory

In group theory, what is meant by the *structure* of a group?
I have an intuitive idea of this (well, I think). e.g.: the structure relates to the operation of the group and its set.

But is there a formal definition of the idea of structure? or it's really just a qualitative term to describe a group?  (and, in fact, many other mathematical objects, like Vector spaces, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no formal definition. Usually by the *structure* of a group some algebraic property concerning the group is meant, referring, say, to a decomposition, a representation as direct or semidirect product, or being simple, solvable, nilpotent or something else in this direction. In some cases the "structure" even means a full classification, e.g., for cyclic groups. Here the structure of such groups is completely known, meaning a complete classification together with all properties, including the knowledge of all subgroups and all quotients.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a formal definition of a notion of structure defined on a set. You can read it in Bourbaki theorie des ensembles, chapitre 4 or here,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure

Comment: Actually, being French speaker, I think I'll go with the Bourbaki version instead (assuming, I'll actually understand some of the mathematics - I'm only in second year).  Just found a link to it here: http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Bourbaki/Theorie%20Des%20Ensembles.pdf